# How to deal with variable with an over-represented value ? (ex : mainly zeros)

Tags: regression, feature-selection

I'm working on a regression issue (I tried both linear regression, also with regularisation like Elasticnet, and random forest to analyze these data).

My goal is to select the most important features (how each feature contributes to explaining the target).

Some features seem to have no real importance in the model.

However, they are mainly also features with lots of values = 0 (ie : for X1, X1=0 for 1400 individuals and X1=1 for 200 individuals).
I wonder if this could be the reason why these features seem unimportant.

Do you know a way to check it ?

NB : I don't speak at all about missing values, we have the information : 0 is the value.

Answer (score 0):

I found some links about over-sampling that may help me :

https://imbalanced-learn.org/stable/over_sampling.html

https://imbalanced-learn.org/stable/generated/imblearn.over_sampling.SMOTE.html

(with the package imbalanced-learn)